# html5 history API handling urls that does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history, html5-history

I'm building a web app that makes use of jquery. For example, when I press a button, all the html in a particular  on front page gets cleared and that div is populated with new contents using jquery. I want this "state" to be represented by a different url. I think the following will achieve the result:

```
history.pushState(null, null, "newdiv");
```

My questions are twofold:

1. There is no resource named "newdiv". The user should be able to achieve the same results as clicking the button (repopulate the div) when he copy pastes the "../newdiv" link on another tab. Usually this gives an error 404 file not found. This should involve calling all the jquery e.t.c. Any examples as to how to do this?
2. Once the new div is populated, the user should be able to go back to the previous state using the back button on the browser. The problem is that the original front page (original div) itself was created using jquery. I read the using "history.popstate()" would achieve this. However, as I am planning to keep separate history for many such jquery calls, I cannot simply redo whatever jquery needs to be done on the original div using history.popstate()

For example:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(){
    //all the jquery needed to reproduce the original div
});
```

is not desirable because pressing the back button from any state (suppose the user have to fill in a multi-stage form and he presses the back button to get the previous form) in my web app would result in the front page.

Is there any way to do these? Parsing the request url in the servlet and redirecting based on that seems possible but sounds like too much work. Just wanted to check before I did something like that.